# ASP.Net MVC: Updating dependent properties with change in a property in same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am facing a bit complex situation, which I am going to explain with an example below.

I have a model like

```
class UserSavings{
    public readonly List<Saving> Quantities = new List<Saving>();
    public decimal Total => Quantities.Sum(q => q.Amount);
}
class Saving{
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
    public int UserId {get;set;}
}
```

While initialising the view I have a dynamic number of users say 5 (but user can't change it). For all users I have to display a textbox to get saving value. In the footer, the total of savings is given like shown below:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            User Id
            </th>
            <th>
            Saving
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var quantity in Model.Quantities)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Displayfor(model => quantity.UserId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => quantity.Saving, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Total
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Total)
            </td>                               
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

But the above html don't work. Now the question is: **How to reflect change in each user's saving into the aggregate total given in the footer.**

Please note that this task is supposed to **DONOT** use any javascript library like knockoutjs, angularjs or any other javascript tool. Just plain razor view.

Comment: you need to do it with javascript.

Comment: If you want to react to client side events (changes in the textbox), then you do need javascript (or you need to submit a form and redirect back to the view)